# event.getForm() function returns different instance of DynamicForm

Tags: smartgwt

I have implemented `ChangedHandler` interface and overrided `onChanged` method.

```
     public class ActionHandler implements ChangedHandler { 
     @Override 
     public void onChanged(ChangedEvent event) { 
            FormItem formItem = event.getItem(); 
            DynForm parent = (DynForm) event.getForm(); 
            performAction(parent); 
     } 
     }
```

In above code if change-event is associated with a boolean 
field (widget is checkbox), I get the same DynForm (in parent 
variable) instance which I rendered in the view (which is what I 
expect). But when ActionHandler is associated with other types of 
field like `string` or `selection` type widget, I get a new instance of 
the DynForm (in parent variable).

Is this a bug or there is some reason for this difference for same 
event with different type of widget?

Actually, I have extended DynForm and in this class I have set some 
parameters, which I require (in my `performAction` function) while the 
different formItem fire their event.

So, I require same instance of DynForm which Is rendered  in the view, 
in all cases when this event is fired, is this possible?

Thanks.